# How to get the number of observations and average for these data using mutate in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large data set, but here is a small of data

```
df<-read.table (text=" F1   M1  Z1  B1
12  10  6   2
11  8   NA  NA
13  NA  4   5

", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the following table

```html
   

 F1 M1  Z1  B1  Z   K   Q   L
    12  10  6   2   4   7.5 56.25   225
    11  8   NA  NA  2   9.5 90.25   180.5
    13  NA  4   5   3   7.333333333 53.77777778 161.3333333
```

Column Z is the number of observations for per row without NA and Column K is the mean per row without NA. Column Q is K^2 an L is Q*Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mutate(), as requested:

```
df%>%mutate(Z=apply(!sapply(df, is.na), 1, sum))%>%
        mutate(K=apply(df,1,function(x)mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)))%>%
        mutate(Q=K^2)%>%
        mutate(L=Q*Z)

  F1 M1 Z1 B1 Z        K        Q        L
1 12 10  6  2 4 7.500000 56.25000 225.0000
2 11  8 NA NA 2 9.500000 90.25000 180.5000
3 13 NA  4  5 3 7.333333 53.77778 161.3333
```

with base R:

```
cbind(df,
        do.call(rbind,apply(df, 1, function(x){
                Z<-sum(!is.na(x))
                K<-mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
                Q<-K^2
                L<-Q*Z
                data.frame(Z, K, Q, L)
        }))
        )

  F1 M1 Z1 B1 Z        K        Q        L
1 12 10  6  2 4 7.500000 56.25000 225.0000
2 11  8 NA NA 2 9.500000 90.25000 180.5000
3 13 NA  4  5 3 7.333333 53.77778 161.3333
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rowSums` and `rowMeans` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Z = rowSums(!is.na(.)), 
         K = rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE), 
         Q = K ^ 2, 
         L = Q*Z)

#  F1 M1 Z1 B1 Z        K        Q        L
#1 12 10  6  2 4 7.500000 56.25000 225.0000
#2 11  8 NA NA 2 9.500000 90.25000 180.5000
#3 13 NA  4  5 3 7.333333 53.77778 161.3333
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Z = sum(!is.na(c(F1, M1, Z1, B1)))) %>% 
  mutate(K = mean(c(F1, M1, Z1, B1), na.rm=T)) %>% 
  mutate(Q = K^2) %>% 
  mutate(L = Q*Z)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 8
# Rowwise: 
     F1    M1    Z1    B1     Z     K     Q     L
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    12    10     6     2     4  7.5   56.2  225 
2    11     8    NA    NA     2  9.5   90.2  180.
3    13    NA     4     5     3  7.33  53.8  161.
```

A more general alternative using c_across:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Z = sum(!is.na(c_across(ends_with("1"))))) %>% 
  mutate(K = mean(c_across(ends_with("1")), na.rm=T)) %>% 
  mutate(Q = K^2) %>% 
  mutate(L = Q*Z)
```